# How to dissaggregate data in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

> ```
>                 Excercise A  Excercise B   Excercise x   Group  Sex
> Person 1           1           4               ...         A     F
> Person 2           2           5               ...         B     F
> Person i           3           5               ...         C     M
> ```

For clarifying reasons, here is an example of my real dataset in Excel:
[Dataset example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvxhn.png). The column "Gimnasta" can be either the index or a normal column, although I have consider it as index. "Plancha" and "Staddler" are columns of exercises, and there are 17 more hidden in the snapshot. "Grupo" and "Sexo" are "Group" and "Sex" respectively.

This data frame needs to be "disaggregated" in order to make a swarm plot for each exercise. This would be an example of what I need:

> ```
>                 Excercise   Score      Group  Sex
> Person 1           A           1        A     F
> Person 1           B           4        A     F
> Person i           C           X        C     M
> ```

The example in Excel:[Final dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSY9O.png)

I have followed the next tutorial: [Pandas: creating dataframe rows from other dataframe information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30829270/pandas-creating-dataframe-rows-from-other-dataframe-information)
However, I am stuck because of the differences between the two examples.

I have split my original df in two for making the process easier (or that is what I think) with the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv",index_col=0)
df2 = df[['Group','Sex']]
df3 = df.drop(df[['Group','Sex']],axis=1)
series = df3.stack()
```

So that we have df2 containing just the columns of Group and Sex and df3 containing all the excercise with their scores, both dataframes with the "Gimnasta" column as index, for making it easy identify the values for each gimnast later on.

I do not know how to continue.

Comment: I'm guessing that your examples are not exactly what your `df` dataset looks like.  Could you provide the code to generate the `df`.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Bill, we are left guessing a bit.
I think ultimately an approach using .melt() will work.

```
data = {u'Exercise A': {0: 1L, 1: 2L, 2: 3L},
 u'Exercise B': {0: 4L, 1: 5L, 2: 5L},
 u'Group': {0: u'A', 1: u'B', 2: u'C'},
 u'Person': {0: u'Person1', 1: u'Person2', 2: u'Person1'},
 u'Sex': {0: u'F', 1: u'F', 2: u'M'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    Exercise A  Exercise B  Group   Person  Sex
0   1           4           A       Person1 F
1   2           5           B       Person2 F
2   3           5           C       Person1 M


df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Person','Group','Sex'], value_vars=['Exercise A', 'Exercise B'],var_name='Exercise', value_name='Score')
df = df.sort_values(['Person','Group'])


    Person  Group   Sex Exercise    Score
0   Person1 A       F   Exercise A  1
3   Person1 A       F   Exercise B  4
2   Person1 C       M   Exercise A  3
5   Person1 C       M   Exercise B  5
1   Person2 B       F   Exercise A  2
4   Person2 B       F   Exercise B  5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to go the .stack() route.

```
data = {u'Exercise A': {0: 1L, 1: 2L, 2: 3L},
 u'Exercise B': {0: 4L, 1: 5L, 2: 5L},
 u'Group': {0: u'A', 1: u'B', 2: u'C'},
 u'Person': {0: u'Person1', 1: u'Person2', 2: u'Person1'},
 u'Sex': {0: u'F', 1: u'F', 2: u'M'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    Exercise A  Exercise B  Group   Person  Sex
0   1           4           A       Person1 F
1   2           5           B       Person2 F
2   3           5           C       Person1 M


df = df.set_index(['Person','Sex','Group'])
df.stack()

Person   Sex  Group            
Person1  F    A      Exercise A    1
                     Exercise B    4
Person2  F    B      Exercise A    2
                     Exercise B    5
Person1  M    C      Exercise A    3
                     Exercise B    5
dtype: int64

which is a series with a 4 level multi_index() where the inner level is 'None'.

names = [x for x in  df.index.names]
names[-1] ='Exercise'
df.index.names = names
df.to_frame('Score')

                                Score
Person  Sex Group   Exercise    
Person1 F   A       Exercise A  1
                    Exercise B  4
Person2 F   B       Exercise A  2
                    Exercise B  5
Person1 M   C       Exercise A  3
                    Exercise B  5
```

you can reset_index() from here.